# How to integrate nock-vcr-recorder-mocha with Meteor?

Tags: http, testing, meteor, mocking, mocha.js

I need to mock HTTP calls when testing my Meteor app using https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-mocha-web

I found https://github.com/poetic/nock-vcr-recorder-mocha but including it in my app using https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm and with the following test code gives me an error...

```
vcr = Meteor.npmRequire('nock-vcr-recorder-mocha')
log "VCR!",vcr

describe "Interpret data", ->
    vcr.it "should work", ->
        chai.expect(->
          # http call
        ).not.to.throw()
```

W20150327-17:25:33.820(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
W20150327-17:25:33.821(1)? (STDERR)     at getCassetteName (/Users/fredrikbranstrom/Sites/kaus/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/nock-vcr-recorder-mocha/lib/it.js:30:24)
W20150327-17:25:33.821(1)? (STDERR)     at /Users/fredrikbranstrom/Sites/kaus/.meteor/local/isopacks/npm-container/npm/node_modules/n